# Query for total should keep on adding with each row of cost Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have table with columns as

```
      Operation             Cost

     Material Issue         10 
     Material Return        20
     X                      30
     Y                      40
     Z                      50
```

I want want a query where columns are

```
     Operation             Cost    Total

     Material Issue         10      10
     Material Return        20      30
     X                      30      60
     Y                      40      100
     Z                      50      150
```

ie.., the the total should keep on adding with each row of cost Column

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        Descr VARCHAR(20),
        Val FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (Descr,Val) SELECT 'X', 10
INSERT INTO @Table (Descr,Val) SELECT 'Y', 20
INSERT INTO @Table (Descr,Val) SELECT 'Z', 50
INSERT INTO @Table (Descr,Val) SELECT 'A', 75
INSERT INTO @Table (Descr,Val) SELECT 'B', 100

SELECT  t1.Descr,
        t1.Val,
        SUM(ISNULL(t2.Val,0))
FROM    @Table t1 LEFT JOIN
        @Table t2 ON t1.ID >= t2.ID
GROUP BY    t1.Descr,
            t1.Val
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to calculate running totals. [This article on SQLTeam](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/calculating-running-totals) covers them and will help you get your query done. The code examples there are easy adaptable, so I let you choose the one which best fits your needs.