# Finding a date from a SUM

Tags: sql, mysql

I am having trouble finding what date my customers hit a certain threshold in how much money they make.

```
customer_id | Amount | created_at
---------------------------
1134       | 10   | 01.01.2010    
1134       | 15   | 02.01.2010    
1134       | 5    | 03.24.2010    
1235       | 10   | 01.03.2010    
1235       | 15   | 01.03.2010    
1235       | 30   | 01.03.2010    
1756       | 50   | 01.05.2010    
1756       | 100  | 01.25.2010
```

To determine how much total amount they made I run a simple query like this:

```
SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount) 
FROM table GROUP BY customer_id
```

But I need to be able to find for e.g. the date a customer hits $100 in total amount.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Jesse,

I believe you are looking for a version of "running total" calculation.

Take a look at this post [calculate-a-running-total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153879/how-do-i-calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-without-using-a-cursor).
There is number of useful links there.

This article have a lot of code that you could reuse as well: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/calculating-running-totals.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Something like having clause

SELECT customer_id, SUM(amount) as Total FROM table GROUP BY customer_id having Total > 100

Comment: Hm, I think that only returns customers that have over $100 in total amount.  I need to find the exact date they hit $100, ie. if a customer has $150 in total amount today, I need to find they date they passed $100.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if MySQL supports subqueries, so take this with a grain of salt:

```
SELECT  customer_id
      , MIN(created_at) AS FirstDate
FROM    ( SELECT    customer_id
                  , created_at
                  , ( SELECT    SUM(amount)
                      FROM      [Table] t
                      WHERE     t.CustomerID = [Table].CustomerID
                                AND t.created_at <= [Table].created_at
                    ) AS RunTot
          FROM      [Table]
        ) x
WHERE   x.RunTot >= 100
GROUP BY customer_id
```