# Group records with incrementing count based on flag

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Take two...

Actual data:

```
division    ID          date            flag
ABC123      ZZZ123      1/17/2013       Y
ABC123      ZZZ123      1/25/2013       N
ABC123      ZZZ123      2/22/2013       Y
ABC123      ZZZ123      2/26/2013       N
ABC123      YYY222      3/20/2013       Y
ABC123      YYY222      5/17/2013       N
XYZ456      ZZZ999      1/15/2012       N
XYZ456      ZZZ999      1/30/2012       N
XYZ456      ZZZ123      2/09/2012       N
XYZ456      ZZZ123      4/13/2012       Y
XYZ456      ZZZ123      6/23/2012       N
XYZ456      ZZZ123      10/5/2012       Y
XYZ456      ZZZ123      11/18/2012      N
```

I need to build a new column, ORDER_group, that will populate based on the following rules:

- Each division and ID combination is considered a "group", sorted by date, and should have an ORDER_group (starting with 1) assigned to it.
- Each time a "group" encounters a flag of "Y", it should increment the ORDER_group by 1.
- If the "group" starts (first record with the earliest date) with a flag = "N", it should still start with ORDER_group = 1.
- If the "group" starts (first record with the earliest date) with a flag = "Y", it should still start with ORDER_group = 1.
- Each subsequent record should be the same ORDER_group number, unless a new "group" (division/ID) is encountered, at which, it should reset back to 1, or the next flag = "Y" is encountered.

Expected results:

```
division    ID          date            flag    ORDER_group
ABC123      ZZZ123      1/17/2013       Y       1
ABC123      ZZZ123      1/25/2013       N       1
ABC123      ZZZ123      2/22/2013       Y       2
ABC123      ZZZ123      2/26/2013       N       2
ABC123      YYY222      3/20/2013       Y       1
ABC123      YYY222      5/17/2013       N       1
XYZ456      ZZZ999      1/15/2012       N       1
XYZ456      ZZZ999      1/30/2012       N       1
XYZ456      ZZZ123      2/09/2012       N       1
XYZ456      ZZZ123      4/13/2012       Y       2
XYZ456      ZZZ123      6/23/2012       N       2
XYZ456      ZZZ123      10/5/2012       Y       3
XYZ456      ZZZ123      11/18/2012      N       3
```

Ideally this should be accomplished without a loop/cursor, unless there are performance reasons with CTE/temp tables.  What is the best way to populate this new column?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

SQL Fiddler for Actual data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cca0/2

Comment: What exactly is your question?  What have you tried?  Please share that additional information.

Comment: Not sure how I completely left my question out.  Updated my original question.  Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: Can you prepare sqlfiddle for that?

Comment: Added fiddler link for sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here a way to do it. It based on [How do I calculate a running total in SQL without using a cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153879/how-do-i-calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-without-using-a-cursor) which does have some flaws. I'm using an index on the advice that it makes the ordering work out *DESPITE* the fact that order on the update is not guaranteed.

And it also worth pointing you to [Calculate running total / running balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310877/calculate-running-total-running-balance/11313533#11313533) for Aaron Bertrand treatment.

The possibly clever bit here is the conversion of Y/N to 1/0 for use in calculating.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (division CHAR(6),ID CHAR(6),dat DATETIME, flag CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES

('ABC123','ZZZ123','01/17/2013','Y')
,('ABC123','ZZZ123','01/25/2013','N')
,('ABC123','ZZZ123','01/25/2013','N')
,('ABC123','ZZZ123','01/25/2013','N')
,('ABC123','ZZZ123','01/25/2013','N')
,('ABC123','ZZZ123','02/22/2013','Y')
,('ABC123','ZZZ123','02/26/2013','N')
,('ABC123','YYY222','03/20/2013','Y')
,('ABC123','YYY222','05/17/2013','N')
,('XYZ456','ZZZ999','01/15/2012','N')
,('XYZ456','ZZZ999','01/30/2012','N')
,('XYZ456','ZZZ123','02/09/2012','N')
,('XYZ456','ZZZ123','04/13/2012','Y')
,('XYZ456','ZZZ123','06/23/2012','N')
,('XYZ456','ZZZ123','010/5/2012','Y')
,('XYZ456','ZZZ123','11/18/2012','N')


CREATE TABLE #Orders (division CHAR(6),    ID CHAR(6),   dat DATETIME, flag CHAR(1),flag_int INTEGER, rn BIGINT, OrderGroup INT)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_Temp_Order ON #Orders(division, id,rn)

INSERT INTO #Orders (division, id,dat,flag,flag_int,rn,OrderGroup)
SELECT division
      ,ID
      ,dat
      ,flag
      ,CASE flag WHEN 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END flag_int
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY division, id ORDER BY dat) rn
      ,0 OrderGroup
  FROM Orders

DECLARE @OrderGroup INT = 0
UPDATE #Orders
   SET @OrderGroup = OrderGroup  = CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE @OrderGroup + flag_int END
  FROM #Orders

SELECT * 
  FROM #Orders
 ORDER BY division
         ,ID
         ,rn

DROP TABLE #Orders
```

Comment: This does appear to work.  I'll run through some bigger tests, but thanks in advance.  I'm not sure why I was trying to over complicate it by using a CTE, when I could have used a few temp tables to accomplish it like you did.

Comment: There are recursive `CTE`s and non-recursive.  The latter can perform the role of a temp table which exists for the life the the query and no longer.

Comment: CTE aren't usually over complicated. I can index a CTE so it not a perfect substitute here. Other than that I suppose I could maybe have UPDATE..OUTPUT a CTE for the same result.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simpler solution?

```
WITH Data AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        Num = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY division, ID ORDER BY date)
    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Data D
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT Count(*)
        FROM Data D2
        WHERE
            D.division = D2.division
            AND D.ID = D2.ID
            AND D.date >= D2.date
            AND (D2.flag = 'Y' OR D2.Num = 1)
    ) G (OrderGroup)
;
```

**[See it live in a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cca0/4)**