# Running total based on Data column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a temp table holding a result of balance changes to an account based on each day.

```
DateValue  DailyAmount
---------- ---------------------------------------
2014-04-21 0.00
2014-04-22 606.28
2014-04-23 -70.00
2014-04-24 -86.96
2014-04-25 -101.01
2014-04-26 -27.00
2014-04-27 0.00
2014-04-28 -75.00
2014-04-29 -12.00
2014-04-30 0.00
2014-05-01 -164.00
2014-05-02 -49.95
2014-05-03 0.00
2014-05-04 0.00
2014-05-05 -140.00
2014-05-06 538.23
2014-05-07 -70.00
2014-05-08 223.04
2014-05-09 0.00
2014-05-10 -50.00
2014-05-11 0.00
2014-05-12 -140.00
2014-05-13 -12.00
2014-05-14 0.00
2014-05-15 6179.81
```

I need to select from this table, adding a running balance, based on an opening balance variable I have.

Is it safe to select, and join to it's self somehow with Dateadd(DAY, -1, Datefield)?

My failed attempt (Wrong results) was this:

```
SELECT DateValue, ISNULL(r.Amount,0) AS DailyAmount, SUM(ISNULL(r.Amount,0))
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN @Result r
ON r.TheDate = c.DateValue
LEFT JOIN @Result r2
ON r2.TheDate = DATEADD(day, -1, r.TheDate)
WHERE c.DateValue BETWEEN @Start AND @End
GROUP BY c.DateValue, r.Amount
```

SQL Version is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2)

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem by adding the code that you've attempted or the desired result. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: May be duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1154139/3430807

Comment: Hamlet - it's 2008 R2.

Comment: @Craig . . . Also show the desired results you want for the data you have provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical way to get a running total in SQL is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select r.*,
       (select sum(r2.DailyAmount)
        from @Result r2
        where r2.DateValue <= r.DateValue
       ) as CumSum
from @Result r;
```

You might want additional conditions in the subquery, such as matching customers.  And, SQL Server 2012 has direct support for cumulative sums.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Gordon.

Comment: Okay. Its called `Corrleated subqueries`. Link - http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm

Comment: Gordon I checked that this query will not work if dates are not in ascending order. Is there a way to still make your query work in that case ? Your @Result = My Sales table. My query `CREATE TABLE ##Sold(
[DateValue] [datetime] NULL,
[DailyAmount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL
)  
insert into ##Sold select top 10 * from sales
order by DailyAmount desc
select * from ##Sold
select r.*,
       (select sum(r2.DailyAmount)
        from ##Sold r2
        where r2.DateValue <= r.DateValue
       ) as CumSum
from ##Sold r;`

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev . . . This should have nothing to do with the dates being in a particular order.  The condition `r2.DateValue <= r.DateValue` is the only condition needed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I swear I saw some strange output. I'll make a fiddle sometime and check again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty extensive discussion of different strategies for running totals on [SQLPerformace.com](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals).

If you only have daily entries than pretty much any solution will do as the performance won't be an issue. I'll show something different then Gordon's just for the sake of it.

```
;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 
        DateValue
       ,DailyAmount
       ,RunningTotal = DailyAmount
         FROM #Result
        ORDER BY DateValue ASC
    UNION ALL
    SELECT y.DateValue
       ,y.DailyAmount
       ,x.RunningTotal + y.DailyAmount
         FROM x 
        INNER JOIN 
        #Result y ON y.DateValue = DATEADD(DAY, 1, x.DateValue)
)
SELECT DateValue
      ,DailyAmount
      ,RunningTotal
    FROM x
    ORDER BY DateValue
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000)
```