# Populating a column with calculated values from another column in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum, insert-update

I have a temporary table (#Temptable3) I'm populating to assist building a dataset to report from. I've solved most logical steps through a bit of trial and error and finding answers to previous questions here (thanks!) however cannot crack this last bit. To simplify, I've removed irrelevant columns from a sample dataset below:

I currently have:

```
RowNumber   Increment   Score
-----------------------------
    1             1     NULL
    2        100000     NULL
    3            -1     NULL
    4             1     NULL
    5            10     NULL
    6            -1     NULL
    7       -100000     NULL
    8           -10     NULL
```

What I'm aiming to get is the score column to populate with the Sum of the Increment column up to and including it's own row e.g.:

```
RowNumber   Increment   Score
-----------------------------
    1          1            1
    2     100000       100001
    3         -1       100000
    4          1       100001
    5         10       100011
    6         -1       100010
    7    -100000           10
    8        -10            0
```

I've tried and failed to get an various update statements to work, playing with self joins, but cannot find anything that looks promising. Apologies if this isn't enough info. Please ask questions if required Thanks for all help.

Thanks to HABO for the pointer to help me find questions on Running sums. A link in [janderssons reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153879/how-do-i-calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-without-using-a-cursor) to a previous question lead me to a solution that worked for me:

declare @runningtotal int
set @runningtotal = 0

update #TempTable3
set @runningtotal = Score = @runningtotal + Increment

from #TempTable3

Comment: What you're looking for is called a _running sum_. Try a little more searching, e.g. `[tsql] running sum`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
SELECT  [RowNumber], Increment
      , SUM(Increment) OVER(ORDER BY [RowNumber]) AS Score
FROM    Your_Table
```

Should do the trick. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

For future readers: Apparently the `over` syntax is available in sql server 2012, but not the `sum() over()`. For an alternative solution (and a more complete solution for an update) see the answer of @JohnCappelletti.

Comment: IMHO - A comment should be required to down vote - even if left as anonymous

Comment: Hi HoneyBadger, thanks for the reply. Like John Cappelletti's solution I also got an "Incorrect syntax near 'order'." message when attempting yours?

Comment: Your version of sql server should support this syntax. Can you tell me more about the error message?

Comment: The error message in full is "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'order'." - Nothing more to add that I can think of - sorry.

Comment: Can you put rownumber in brackets? ([]) (see edit) rownumber is also a function...

Comment: Still no change in the error message i'm afraid. :-(

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @Table table (RowNumber int,Increment int,score int)
Insert into @Table values
(1,1,NULL),
(2,100000,NULL ),
(3,-1,NULL), 
(4,1,NULL), 
(5,10,NULL), 
(6,-1,NULL), 
(7,-100000,NULL),
(8,-10,NULL)

Update @Table Set Score=B.Score
 From  @Table A 
 Join (Select RowNumber,Score=sum(Increment) over (order by RowNumber) from @Table) B
  on  A.RowNumber=B.RowNumber

Select * from @Table
```

OR

```
UPDATE @Table SET Score=(SELECT SUM(Increment) 
                          FROM  @Table B 
                          WHERE  b.RowNumber <= A.RowNumber)
FROM @Table A
```

Returns

```
  RowNumber Increment       score
    1           1           1
    2           100000      100001
    3           -1          100000
    4           1           100001
    5           10          100011
    6           -1          100010
    7           -100000     10
    8           -10         0
```

Comment: Hello John - thanks for the prompt reply, I'd tried your solution above, substituting my table name as appropriate but got the message "Incorrect syntax near 'order'." I tried pasting yours into a clean query window and ran as is and got the same message. Not sure if relevant, I'm in T-SQL? MS SQL SMS 2008 R2

Comment: What version of SQL  2008+ ?

Comment: There are 3 @Table's  did you do all three?

Comment: Version info... Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.50.6000.34
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      10.50.6000.34
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.0.8112.16421
Microsoft .NET Framework      2.0.50727.5485
Operating System      6.1.7601

Comment: Select @@Version   will give you the version of the SQL Server

Comment: Can you run the script as provided?  .. without replacing @Table

Comment: When translating to my query I didn't declare and populate as my table aready exists as '#TempTable3' with data in it. I put in the remainder from 'update' onwards, changing the '@Table' to '#TempTable3'  as appropriate. Otherwise left it as written. The only other thing of note is that the intellisense has underlined the 'B.PeriodScore' as an invalid column name.

Comment: Select @@ Version gives Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64)   Apr 22 2011 19:23:43   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: I ran as provided in a clean query window, including the declare and insert statements and got the same "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'order'." Thanks for continued assistance!

Comment: Please ignore the intellisense underline, that was caused by a mis-key on my part

Comment: I'm at a loss. Even went to MS to confirm the OVER clause was in 2008.

Comment: Fair enough and thanks for efforts - I'm currently exploring running sums as advised by HABO above.

Comment: Updated my answer see after OR

Comment: That works! Thanks for persevering John. I have up-voted but as a new user, don;t have a reputation score high enough for this to show yet? As an aside your solution that worked after to OR had a slower run time than the one I had found after searching with HABO's suggested search criteria. I'm still grateful though.

Comment: No worries.  Turns out the OVER clause is supported in 2008, BUT SUM() OVER is not.   Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the pointer from HABO to help me find previous questions on Running sums. A link in [janderssons reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153879/how-do-i-calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-without-using-a-cursor) to a previous question lead me to a solution that worked for me:

declare @runningtotal int set @runningtotal = 0

update #TempTable3 set @runningtotal = Score = @runningtotal + Increment

from #TempTable3

Thanks again to HoneyBadger JohnCappelletti for persevering with me, I'm sure the fault was probably mine.

Comment: Without specifying an explicit order, SQL Server may update the rows in any order. Solution like John Cappeletti's ensure that the sums are calculated based on the correct rows. Depending on the version of SQL Server you're using, [`LAG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) may be useful. (It helps if you tag database questions with both the software and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`.)